# How to realize the shutdown using code

Tags: android

is there a methods to keep  mobile phone off using code, i have no idea about this,and hope someone give me some advice,or example , code,api

thank you

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, if your app did this, it would probably get shutdown from Market. Your app would basically hijack the phone. Sounds like a virus if all your app did was kept your phone off...

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a bit ?
Do you want to keep the phone from being able to boot? -> that would be virus like behavior without any "good" use. - or do you want to implement theft protection app, so if stolen the owner can "lock" the phone ?

Comment: when deep into the night ,i donot receive message which come from my friends after three o'clock,so i have sleeping  i donot wake up to close my phone,I want to shutDown my phone automatic.
i donot know who give me "-1", why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete example :
https://github.com/rbochet/AutoShutdown

More accurately: https://github.com/rbochet/AutoShutdown/blob/master/src/org/servalproject/autoshutdown/UnlockWatcher.java#L71

Requires root.

Comment: i test your code,but i cannot reboot my device. i think your code not reboot if frist my close my device

Comment: i close the device,are you know how to reboot the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect shutdown is occurring by using an Intent Receiver for the ACTION_SHUTDOWN intent. This is intended to make sure applications save any required information to disk that is specific to shutting down to prevent loss of user information.

[See how to use Intents here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

[See how to use the ACTION_SHUTDOWN intent here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN)

As for stopping shutdown, I'm pretty sure it's not possible on Android.

Comment: As a developer normally you don't have to care about the action_shutdown intent if you use the onPause method correct

Comment: thank you ,i used this
try{
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
      out.writeBytes("reboot -p\n");
      out.writeBytes("exit\n");
      out.flush();
 //process2.waitFor();
     }catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

also i want to know reflection ,whether is a correct matheds

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to say here

Comment: What he wants is to have his app shutdown the phone, not listen for when it's shutting down...