# shut down android device programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to switch off android device through my program. It actually gets switched off but it restarts itself. I want the phone not to restart again by itself. How can I do that?

Comment: Second result while using the search terms "[android] turn off phone"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591993/how-to-turn-off-android-phone-programmatically

Comment: You will need the device to have root access first.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305491/power-off-or-restart-an-android-device-via-code-program

Comment: i have checked all those links but they all are for rebooting the device. i want to shut down the device

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to shutdown an android mobile programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411650/how-to-shutdown-an-android-mobile-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked on StackOverflow in the past. The effective answer is that you would require the `DEVICE_POWER` permission in order to shut the phone completely off, but the user would need a rooted phone to give your app permission to that control anyway.

Best you could hope for is `PowerManager.goToSleep()`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have found the answer,but this might help other users.

It's not possible to turn off  your device. 
Here is an easy way to lock it :

- Download an application that locks/turns off the screen
- Launch it from your application [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application)

You won't need any permissions, because some are only granted for system apps(like DEVICE_POWER and REBOOT).
You also won't need to root your device.