# Turn off tablet when user log out from my application

Tags: android

I am developing a tablet application for school and my requirement is to turn off my tablet, when user clicks on log out button provided in my application. This because I don't want to give any other access to users.

Can anybody tell me, is it possible? If yes, then how can I do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone/3745548#3745548), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860399/shut-down-android-device-programmatically).

Answer (score 2):

Actually.. the answer for this question is no if you are developing an ordinary sdk 
application.

Answer from Commonsware:

```
 Only applications signed with the system firmware signing key can do this.
```

EDIT:

Check this answer from [Michalis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656925/2219600)

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply.. but i dont know how to sign my application with system firware..?? can you help me out..

Comment: Perhaps, if you have root privileges you can do this too.