# How to power off an Android device programmatically

Tags: android

How can you power off an Android device programmatically?

I searched for an answer, some said your phone must be rooted (I don't want to do that), and others said it's impossible.

Is it really impossible?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3745548/905349) answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it unless you have a rooted phone. Then it is as easy as calling the shutdown command for linux:

```
void shutdown()
{

    try {
          Process m_process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
          DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(m_process.getOutputStream());
          os.writeBytes("shutdown\n");
          os.flush();
          m_process.waitFor();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some devices doesn't have shutdown, you can try too with "reboot -p"

Comment: unfortunately  it's not working .
are you sure for this ? it's work

Comment: as said, this will only work if your phone is rooted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you want but try using this:
http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/togglelibrary.12388/#post69639

I haven't tested that library but maybe goToSleep method will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can find another [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591993/how-to-turn-off-android-phone-programmatically) in StackOverflow, it is not possible in non rooted phones, this is deliberate, you don't want to allow third party apps to turn off your device that will create undesired behaviors in your phone if you install the wrong application.