# Can we ON or OFF the device programatically?

Tags: android

*I know there is a way where we can reboot the device. And it shows immediate result.*

But my need is as :-

I want that when I will be in my class-room my phone automatically goes to OFF. (Lets say at 2:00 PM), and when I will end my class, my phone will automatically ON (Lets say at 5:00 PM).

So I am looking for the ways where I can ON/OFF the device automatically.

***Is this possible? If yes how can I do it?***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone check this...

Comment: "I know there is a way where we can reboot the device. And it shows immediate result." -- you cannot hold the permission necessary to do this, as indicated by the link in the previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Third party applications do not have the permission to do that.

Check out these links

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN

Answer (score 3):

No. Once ot goes off it cannot be turned on. I think you need to totally **mute** your phone rather than turning it off.

Comment: Actually some simple phones when you set the alarm and turn off the phone, phone used to ON at the alarm time. So I think it is possible to ON the device. Am I right?

Comment: @user594955 That sounds like stand-by.

Comment: may be some sleep function are use with locking so you can wack with countdowntime

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want your phone to receive calls and connect to any networks, [enabling/disabling the AirplaneMode](http://www.anddev.org/how_to_set_airplane_mode_on-off-t4454.html) by using a [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) (or a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)) might be a better idea.

Comment: Nice! If I won't get answer of my need, This must be my fav option.

Comment: I wouldn't use a `Timer` here, but rather `AlarmManager`. `Timer` would require a service to be in memory 24x7, which is unlikely to occur. That being said, airplane mode or muting the phone are possible, while shutting it down is not possible.

Comment: That was what i was originally searching for... THX.