# how to shut down Android device

Tags: android, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)

how can I shut down the Android Device via my application ? Is it possible to shut down the Android device ? How ?

Are there requirements ?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone

Comment: Why would you want to do this?