# How to power off programmatically a rooted phone ?

Tags: android

I want to power of my device programically my phone is rooted  but this command not power of my device what is wrong ?

```
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
               Process chperm;
                try {
                    chperm=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                      DataOutputStream os = 
                          new DataOutputStream(chperm.getOutputStream());

                          os.writeBytes("reboot -p\n");
                          os.flush();



                         chperm.waitFor();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    });
```

How do I power off device programtically ?

Comment: Bravo !!! You rooted your phone for testing.

Comment: yes my application require to power off from application

Comment: So, you'll sell it only to rooted users?

Comment: i found solution my self change the permission of system/bin/reboot file it will work

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will work for you.

```
Intent shutdown = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
    shutdown.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
    shutdown.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    thisActivity.startActivity(shutdown);
```

Comment: I think this will work without rooting. Moreover it is only shuting down the phone, Who will turn it on ?

Comment: not working it  require grandacccess permission from Super user when i allow it nothing perform

Comment: you have to use singing your apk with system key. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Use android/out/host/<your-host>/framework/signapk.jar to sign your app with below listed Files
   - platform.x509.pem 
   - platform.pk8
Located in android/build/target/product/security. And then use bellow command:- java -jar signapk.jar platform.x509.pem platform.pk8 <YourApp-unsigned.apk> <YourApp-signed.apk>

Answer (score 1):

this is actually an answer from stackoverflow it self in a different thread.
[Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use this code, you need Super User! Works on 4.0 and above!

```
 Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
            i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
```