# Can I make an android application that should turn my phone off automatically when the user has passed a certain deadline?

Tags: android, kernel

I am working on a project and still thinking if it can work to make an android application that should turn the phone completely off when the user has passed a certain deadline. and even if the user reset his settings the application still working. is it possible to do something like this ?

Thanks.

Comment: No you cannot. Look at the comment of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3745555/1584654). As said only applications signed with the system firmware signing key can do a reboot.

Comment: @Joseph82 your right on "non-rooted" devices... My S6 will turn off by the code you can find below.

Comment: Of course, I was talking about non-rooted devices ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will work (**if rooted**)...

call

```
runRootCmd("reboot -p"); // "-p" will power off
```

method:

```
public static void runRootCmd(String cmd) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(cmd)) {
            return;
        }
        Process process;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                    process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(cmd + " ;\n");
            os.flush();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int read;
            InputStream errIs = process.getErrorStream();
            while ((read = errIs.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(read);
            }
            baos.write('\n');

            InputStream inIs = process.getInputStream();
            while ((read = inIs.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(read);
            }

            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            String result = new String(data);

            Log.d(TAG, "runRootCmd result: " + result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I am new to this, but the application should also prevent the user from turning the phone on or turning it on with an activation key or something !