# How to switch off android phone programatically

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I want to switch off android phone when clicking a button in android application. Is it possible..

How can I give system permission to my project.

Can any one guide me to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
```

i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true);
startActivity(i);

Comment: It ask to system permission. How can I giving permission to shutdown.