# Boot android, if there is power

Tags: android, boot

There is such a task - to include an android device, if there is power and turn off programmatically. I know that in order to turn off, you need a root (it will). But is there any way to turn on the device if the power is applied?

Comment: It's entirely dependent on the hardware, not software. If the main board has a jumper that powers on the device when an input voltage is detected, then it will do so. This is mainly for Android devices that do not have a battery, mind. If not, you'd need to hold the power button as usual.

Comment: For turn off the device you can visit the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone

Comment: Thanks for suggestion adout turn off, I will it.
About boot: in my case I can set timer in android settings, so device will turn on at 5:00AM (for example). For me it fits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my case I can use system scheduler for boot device at specialised time (f.e. 5:00 AM) and with `root access` shutdown device with this code

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime()
           .exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", "reboot -p" })
           .waitFor();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```