# Turning off an Android device at a specific time

Tags: android, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically switching off Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745523/programmatically-switching-off-android-phone)

Is it possible to write an application that turns off (not reboot) an Android device? For example, it plays a song and after 30 minutes, turns the device off, automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927083/how-to-realize-the-shutdown-using-code/ - this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Already aswered here.... 
[Why does my app throw an `android.permission.REBOOT SecurityException`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456467/why-does-my-app-throw-an-android-permission-reboot-securityexception)

Unless you have the manufacturer key to sign your app/or if your device is rooted..it is not possible to turf it off.